# how to change "this" context while using selection.call()

Tags: d3.js

I'm making a plugin for creating legends following Mike Bostock's [*Towards Reusable Charts*](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/).

Here below is the simplified code:

```js
function legend () {
    var width      = null,
        height     = null;

  // implement closures with getter-setter methods.
  draw.width = function (val) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return width; }
    width = val;
    return draw;
  };
  draw.height = function (val) { /* same as draw.with pattern */ };

  function draw (selection) {
    /* using selection to draw something */
  }

  return draw;
}
```

This pattern works well

```js
var lgd = legend().width(400).height(300);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .call(lgd);
```

However, I change the closure variants as properties for some reasons.

Then the code changed like this:

```js
function Legend () {
  this._width = null;
  this._heigth = null;
  this.someProporty = null;
}
Legend.prototype.width = function (val) {
  if (!arguments.length) { return this._width; }
  this._width = val;
  return this;
};
Legend.prototype.height = function (val) { /* same as with */ };

Legend.prototype.draw = function (selection) {
  if (this.someProporty) { /* Oops, "this" is not the "Legend" instance */ }

  /* using selection to draw something */
};
```

Now the problem is the function `Legend.prototype.draw` need to access `Legend` instance(`this`)'s proporty, when I follow the same pattern the `this` is become the selection object:

```
var legend = (new Legend()).width(400).height(300);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .call(legend.draw);     // Oops, "this" is not the "Legend" instance
```

I can achieve it by one of this:

- `selection.call(legend.draw.bind(legend))`
- `legend.draw(selection)`

However, is anyone can give me some elegant ways?

Comment: I kind of like the first pattern for this, I've noticed a lot of other d3 libraries don't go for the prototype based approach (probably because of the reasons you've encountered). From your current situation I think the easiest way forward would be method that returned the bound draw function, not sure how you rate that on elegance though.

Comment: @JoshRumbut  reasonable!

Comment: Since you mentioned that `this` is pointing to the selection instead of your instance, I deduce that you are using D3 v3, because from v4 up `this` would be `null`. Given that, the docs on [`selection.call()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#call) are pretty clear on how to solve your case; at the end of the methods description even is an example covering exactly your problem. The documentation also suggests using `.bind()` to have `this` point to your instance.

Comment: @altocumulus Yes I'm using d3-v3. I know how to use `bind()`, but just feel a litter annoying. Finally, I decide to split the `draw` method from `Legend.prototype` and give every `Legend` instance a binded `draw` method. Functionally speaking, it works.

Comment: @altocumulus Upgraded to v4 recently and, effectively, in v4 `this` is null in those cases, but I had a bad time trying to track it down, because I didn't find anything about it in https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/v4.13.0/CHANGES.md nor https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.3.0/README.md
How did you know a null context was the expected behaviour?

Comment: @40detectives It's in the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection): *"The selection.call method no longer sets the this context when invoking the specified function; the selection is passed as the first argument to the function, so use that."*